# How can I extract a URL's extension with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, url

I would like to extract the file extension from a url. For example, `http://www.url.com/index.html`. I would something like a function `extension`, where `extension(http://www.url.com/index.html)` return `http`. The task is trivial in the case of the URL I have given, but what if I have query parameters, i.e. `http://www.url.com/index.html?q=bar`?

**UPDATE**:

This is what I've gotten so far:

```
function extension(url) {
    var components = url.split('/');
    var lastComponent = components[components.length-1];
    return lastComponent.split('?')[0].split('.')[1];
}
```

I have't tested it extensively yet. Is there better?

Comment: You might be able to do this a little more robustly with [Regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), but I don't think there's anything wrong with your solution, other than the fact that a filename might have more than one `.` in it in some cases. It might be worth getting the last element after splitting by `.`, rather than the one at index 1. This is total nitpicking though :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done without introducing `var`s, as:

```
var fileExtension = function( url ) {
    return url.split('.').pop().split(/\#|\?/)[0];
}
```